# Custom Javascript not working in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, arrays, wordpress, foreach

My intent is to add an excerpt to each portfolio card within a grid (currently, these only show an image, title and category).

I found a way to insert the excerpt into a card and to iterate through all the cards, but excerpt is not inserting into all of the cards even though the loop is working as expected (logging each iteration). The excerpt will only insert into one card if I specific a specific index of the targetsArray. I left this line commented out for reference.

```
window.onload = function() {
    let targets = document.querySelectorAll('.entry-title');
    let newElem = document.createElement('p');
    let excerpt = 'This will be the excerpt...';
    newElem.innerHTML = excerpt;
    
    let targetsArray = [];
    
    for (let i = 0; i < targets.length; i++) {
      targetsArray.push(targets[i]);
    }
    
    targetsArray.forEach(target => {
      console.log(target);
      target.parentNode.insertBefore(newElem, target.nextSibling);
    });
    // targetsArray[1].parentNode.insertBefore(newElem, targetsArray[1].nextSibling);
    
  };
```

Note: If you're wondering why I didn't use a simplier method for converting the nodes list into an array, it is because they weren't working.

I tried

```
const targets = [...document.querySelectorAll(".entry-title")];
```

and...

```
Array.from(targets)
```

For reference this is the page I'm trying to make these changes to
[equipourkids.org](https://equipourkids.org/parents-online-resources/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are trying to do it with pure JS for a specific reason but Wordpress already loads jQuery by default (if you didn't remove it) and doing that with jQuery should be much more simple then that.

```
let targets = $('.entry-title');
let newElem = $('<p>This will be the excerpt...</p>')
        
targets.each(function (idx, item){
    $(item).parent().insertBefore(newElem);
});
```

I just don't understand where exactly you want to insert those exceprt based on your HTML structure. Should that be inside entry-info or what?

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that. The excerpt should be inside entry-header. I just tried your code and got this error: **Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function** . Perhaps it's due to the Phlox theme they are using?

Comment: Argh sorry, you need to use jQuery instead of $. Just replace "$" with "jQuery" and you should be fine